# insert into with two selects and compare

Tags: sql, sql-server

It looks stupid in this example but here is what I want to do:

Table_a:

```
id    fk_b_id              full_name
1     [I want '10' here]   [I want 'John, Doe' here]
```

Table_b:

```
id    first_name
10    John
```

Table_c:

```
id    full_name    date
20    John, Doe    2020-01-01
```

I get all the full names that is not already in c and meets the criteria like this:

```
select distinct full_name
from Table_c
where full_name not in (
    select full_name
    from Table_a ) and date > GETDATE()
```

The result from the query should be inserted into Table_a together with Table_b's id (fk_b_id). So I need a compare between part of Table_a's full_name and Table_b's first_name to get the correct fk. I can do the compare like this:

```
where Table_b.first_name = LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(Table_c.full_name, CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(Table_c.full_name))-1 )))
```

Can I insert all the full names from table c (that meets the criteria) and the fk from table b (where their first names match) into table a in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just use your condition to JOIN between tables B and C

```
INSERT INTO Table_a (fk_b_id, full_name)
SELECT DISTINCT b.id, c.full_name 
FROM Table_c c
INNER JOIN Table_b b ON b.first_name = LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(c.full_name, CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(c.full_name))-1 )))
WHERE c.full_name not in (
    select a.full_name
    from Table_a a ) and c.date > GETDATE()
```

EDIT:

Also note, that if your `table_a.full_name` column can have NULL values, `NOT IN` sub-query will fail to give you expected results. I suggest rewriting it to use `NOT EXISTS`

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT * FROM Table_a WHERE Table_a.Full_Name = Table_c.FUll_Name )
```

Comment: Thank you that was what I was after =)